# MySQL while loop only loops once

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database `activities` that stores activities information such as attendees, event description, event time, etc.

I call a while statement to print out the data, however the while loops is only looping once:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `activities` ORDER BY `date`");
while($act = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
   //do some stuff
}
```

I did a `var_dump` of `$result`, and this is printed out:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(11) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(26) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, can someone help? thanks!

Comment: Well it looks all ok. You're sure that this statement returns more than one result?

Comment: This statement only returns the first event within the database; I have numerous events in there.

Comment: did you try running your sql query in database

Comment: @MujtabaHaider, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: copy your query "SELECT * FROM `activities` ORDER BY `date`" and run in your db and see result first there

Comment: So in your while loop you doing a print_r($act) and its only showing 1 result?

Comment: @MujtabaHaider, ah I see. I ran it in there, and everything worked out.

Comment: more than one records?

Comment: @Rob, yeah that's what happens.

Comment: @MujtabaHaider, yep all the records in the database print out

Comment: @Rob, it's still printing the first row.

Comment: You not overwriting $result in the loop are you?

Comment: @Rob, your statement checked out. I looked into my later code and realized that I used $result again to retrieve data from another table.

Comment: lol it happens and can be really irating when you don’t see it. Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments on the question. Overwriting $result was the cause of this problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is supposed to work.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `activities` ORDER BY `activities`.`date`");

while($act = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
   //do some stuff
}
```